Detect powerbank low battery level with a Raspberry Pi
I'm using a powerbank to power a Raspberry Pi and small screen.
I'd like the Raspberry Pi to detect when the powerbank battery is low:

to prevent the system to prematurely shut off
to give visual feedback that the battery needs to be charged (I can manage this part)

What I've tried so far / ideas:

The powerbank has a regulated 5V output, so I can't detect the battery level from there.
My only idea is to open the powerbank and read voltage directly from the internal battery, but I want to explore other options first
I tried to read voltage from the micro USB port (the one to charge the powerbank), but it doesn't read any value.
The powerbank has a numerical display to show the % battery level, but I'm not sure how I can leverage that.

Questions:

Is there another way to detect low battery?
How to read the battery level from the Raspberry Pi?

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!

The Universal Serial Bus Power Delivery Specification has a Battery_Status Message. Does the Raspberry Pi and your power bank support exchanging USB Power Delivery messages? This is a comment, and not an answer, as I haven't verified if the hardware and Raspberry Pi software support exchanging USB Power Delivery messages.

You could read the numerical display optically BUT that is far harder than accessing the internal battery voltage. An RP ADC would allow voltage to be read.

Isn't there multiple different battery "hats" available for RPi that can return battery status?

@Justme I think there are, but I had a spare powerbank and my project required a large battery capacity that usually hat don't have.

@ChesterGillon Good idea, thans for sharing. My Pi is a Pi zero v1 which only have micro usb ports, I don't think Power delivery protocol is supported. Besides, from what I read online, most powerbanks don't implement this protocol unfortunately
